# Couldn't resolve error at 'nt! swapcontext' in Windbg

Tags: windows, windbg

OK so I ran the following command from the Windbg command prompt as follows:

```
lkd> uf nt! swapcontext
```

and got the following error:

```
Couldn't resolve error at 'nt! swapcontext'
```

I then ran the following command from the Windbg command prompt:

```
.reload /f /v ntoskrnl.exe
```

and got the following output:

```
lkd> .reload /f /v ntoskrnl.exe
AddImage: \SystemRoot\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
 DllBase  = fffff802`3580a000
 Size     = 0077a000
 Checksum = 007122c1
 TimeDateStamp = 623d2df2
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x10
         C:\symbolcache*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         ntkrnlmp.pdb
         610455A6355B4DEFB6BAA86D9F7967EE1
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\symbolcache\ntkrnlmp.pdb\610455A6355B4DEFB6BAA86D9F7967EE1\ntkrnlmp.pdb - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\symbolcache\ntkrnlmp.pdb\610455A6355B4DEFB6BAA86D9F7967EE1\ntkrnlmp.pd_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\symbolcache\ntkrnlmp.pdb\610455A6355B4DEFB6BAA86D9F7967EE1\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/ntkrnlmp.pdb/610455A6355B4DEFB6BAA86D9F7967EE1/ntkrnlmp.pdb
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/ntkrnlmp.pdb/610455A6355B4DEFB6BAA86D9F7967EE1/ntkrnlmp.pd_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/ntkrnlmp.pdb/610455A6355B4DEFB6BAA86D9F7967EE1/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: ntkrnlmp.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: nt - export symbols
```

My _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable is set to the following:
c:\symbols;cache*c:\symbolcache;\server\symbols;SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

Do the errors indicate that there is a problem with the Microsoft Symbol Server i.e. symbol file not found on the server or could it be that there is a configuration issue on my end ? I'm running Visual Studio 2019 and Windbg on Windows 8.1.

Comment: The Microsoft symbol server does not have all symbols. The symbols for XP have been deleted and some 10 insider builds might be missing. Which version are you debugging?

Comment: @Anders I was able to view the symbols for SwapContext and KiSwapContext before my computer was updated by windows. Now I'm unable to view the dissembly in Windbg.

Comment: Ntoskrnl.exe version 6.3.9600.20334.